# Flag incomplete output from ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a script that uses FFMPEG to convert many files. If I stop it, the file it was currently outputting will be kept in an incomplete state.

Is there a way to have FFMPEG write to a temporary file (say FILENAME_incomplete) so I can easily identify aborted conversions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're manually aborting it, then this isn't implemented since ffmpeg has no concept of progress per se. It doesn't know that an output will be 200 seconds long and so if stopped at 100 sec, the processing was therefore incomplete.

If ffmpeg stops due to an error, its exit code will be > 0. So, you can catch that and delete the corresponding output file.

Comment: I don't understand what "ffmpeg has no concept of progress" means in this context. As an example `-movflags +faststart` seems run at completion, which would be the relevant signal.

Comment: faststart applies to MOV family of formats like MP4 and is carried out by the MOV muxer. It doesn't happen at completion. It happens when the MOV muxer encounters end of stream on the last stream or when ffmpeg receives SIGINT. It doesn't know in advance if or when either of those things will happen.

Comment: You clearly know much more about FFMPEG internals than me and I don't intend to argue. I can wrap FFMPEG in something that will handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Well reading the error code is one way, however it's not fail safe - say if the terminal is killed or something.

You could name of your output file like `Filename.incomplete.mpeg` then on the line after `ffmpeg` in your script check that the exit code (`$?` for `bash` scripts) is 0, in which case the assumption is that `ffmpeg` completed normally and you can rename the file to `Filename.mpeg`.

I've also noticed that incorrupted output has a corrupt timeline. There are probably ways to check that the output file is complete (using `ffprobe` maybe).